# Can anyone tell the space complexity of this code?

Tags: java

So this is a question of gfg to find union of two arrays and following is my code:

```java
class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            int testcase = Integer.parseInt(buff.readLine());
            while(testcase-->0) {
                String[] input  = buff.readLine().split(" ");
                int size1 = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
                int size2 = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
                
                Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            
                String[] inp1 = buff.readLine().split(" ");
                String[] inp2 = buff.readLine().split(" ");
            
                for(int i = 0; i < inp1.length; i++){
                    set.add(Integer.parseInt(inp1[i]));
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < inp2.length; i++){
                    set.add(Integer.parseInt(inp2[i]));
                }
                System.out.println(set.size());
     
            }
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

The expected time and auxiliary space complexity for this program is given as: O(N+M) where N and M are size of two arrays respectively.

So can anyone tell what is space complexity for above code.I am so confused about the space complexity for this code.

Comment: What is `while(testcase-->0)`?

Comment: @Glains `while(testcase-- > 0)`

Comment: It is the combined size of two arrays that you have in memory (sum of size of `inp1` and `inp2`)

Comment: @user7 I got confused by the formatting, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Glains sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: @user7 what about the space complexity of the hashset that i have used? will it be counted as auxiliary space?

Comment: Total space complexity seems 2N (lenth of array1 and it's corresponding HashSet) + 2M (length of array2 and it's corresponding HashSet). So we can say it is O(N + M)

Comment: @MohammadZulfikar yeah i was thinking same but i got bit confused because of the term auxiliary space complexity

Comment: Hmmm... Auxiliary space used here maybe because arrays are just being used for temporary use but ultimately you will have the items stored in the Set and it will have elements of array1 and array2 so it should be O(M + N)

Comment: If you not already read then give it a read: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-86/#:~:text=Auxiliary%20Space%20is%20the%20extra,and%20space%20used%20by%20input.